# Impossible to access to my-domain:8080 with varnish

Tags: apache-2.2, varnish

I've just setup varnish server, for now I made him run on the 8080 port and my Apache2 is on the 80.

If I try : http://www.seek-team.com:8080 => no response.

I tryed to switch ports, (varnish on 80 and apache2 on 8080) and I end up with a 503 with a Guru meditation

```
Error 503 Service Unavailable  
Service Unavailable 
Guru Meditation:  XID: 1350923555  
Varnish cache server
```

**Here's my [.vcl](https://gist.github.com/bba902cfa9f875abbb34)**

PS: I've edited `/etc/default/varnish` to tell to listen to 8080

```
netstat -lp | grep varnish
tcp        0      0 tristan-web.fr:6082     *:*                     LISTEN      17046/varnishd  
tcp        0      0 *:http-alt              *:*                     LISTEN      17047/varnishd  
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http-alt           [::]:*                  LISTEN      17047/varnishd

netstat -lp | grep apache
tcp6       0      0 [::]:www                [::]:*                  LISTEN      15812/apache2   
tcp6       0      0 [::]:https              [::]:*                  LISTEN      15812/apache2   
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6572942  15812/apache2       /var/run/wsgi.15812.0.1.sock
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Define "no response".  Logs, tcpdumps, firewall rules, and apache configuration would also be handy information to have.

Comment: Did you change your backend definition appropriately when you changed what was listening where?  You've got varnish connecting to the port that varnish listens on.  What output do you get from `varnishlog`?

Answer (score 0):

The port 8080 wasn't accessible from the web and locally, so that explains why varnish didn't hit apache.